# Geopandas reading gdb layer name to object in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

I have a list of layers an I want to import them to geopandas and have their object name to be the same as the layer name.

In this case `layer = gpd.read_file(...)` should be the name of the actual layer from the layerlist.

```
layerlist = fiona.listlayers(gdb)

for layer in layerlist:
    layer = gpd.read_file(gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer=layer)
```

The manual way to achieve what I want is:

```
roads = gpd.read_file(gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer='roads')
trees = gpd.read_file(gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer='trees')
signs= gpd.read_file(gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer='signs')
...
```

But I'd rather loop through the layers so I don't need to look into the layer names first.

Comment: I've tried to use ,format() `'{}'.format(layer) = gpd.read_file(gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer=layer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not an easy thing to do in Python I would advise against it anyway. You can use a dictionary with keys equal to layer names.

```py
layers = {}

layerlist = fiona.listlayers(gdb)

for layer in layerlist:
    layers[layer] = gpd.read_file(gdb, driver="FileGDB", layer=layer)
```

Then you can access each of them easily from a dict.

```
layers['roads']
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be the best way forwards, trying to setup a geodb migration routine for a client with strict data standards on both sides. I'll ponder on this answer.